# How to get a value of a model field in django actions?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm trying to do a action in my admin app, and in this action I must retrieve the value of a field that is in my model app. But I'm not getting success.

My model app:

```
class Entrada(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    medicamento = models.ForeignKey(Medicamento, verbose_name=_(u'Medicamento'))
    serial = models.AutoField(_(u'Serial'), null=False, blank=False, unique=True, db_index=True, primary_key=True)
    validade = models.DateField(_(u'Validade'), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    lote = models.CharField(_(u'Lote do fabricante'), null=False, blank=False, max_length=20)
    quantidade = models.PositiveIntegerField(_(u'Quantidade'), null=False)
    mud = models.PositiveIntegerField(_(u'Menor unidade de dispensa'), null=False)
    data_entrada = models.DateField(_(u'Data de entrada'), default=timezone.now())
```

My admin app:

```
def print_barcode(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    path_output = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, Entrada.serial)
    cmd = settings.BARCODE_COMMAND.format(Entrada.serial, path_output)


class EntradaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['medicamento_descricao', 'serial', 'quantidade', 'medicamento_estoque', 'data_entrada', 'usuario']
    search_fields = ['medicamento__descricao']
    action = [print_barcode]

    class Meta:
         model = Entrada
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to get a property from the model CLASS. What you need to do is get the property from an instantiation of that model class.

```
model_obj = Entrada.objects.get(id=some_id)

def print_barcode(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    path_output = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, model_obj.serial)
    cmd = settings.BARCODE_COMMAND.format(model_obj.serial, path_output)
```

Comment: Unless you don't want to be using a model at all, I'd need more context to understand what you are trying to do, as well as an error message.

Comment: Thanks J___, but now I'm having another problem. The action is not appearing in the admin. I think I'm not using it right